# simultaneous definition of a static property of the same name than an instance property in fsharp

Tags: f#, static, properties, overriding

I would like to be able to use both style

```
      let refdataservice  = BBGReferenceData.Acquire
         //some code
      BBGReferenceData.Release
```

and

```
      let refdataservice  = BBGReferenceData.Acquire
         //some code
       refdataservice.Release
```

However I cant seem to simultaneously define a static property and an instance property of the same name.

```
  static member Release with get() = counter <- counter - 1
                                     if counter = 0 then instance.Value.Stop()
  //does not work, tells me that Release is not a static property
  member x.Release with get() = BBGSession.Release
```

Trying to override does not work either

```
  //'No abstract property was found that corresponds to this override'
  override x.Release with get() = BBGSession.Release
```

How can I circumvent this ?

Comment: Are you on a current version of F# - old compilers would fail to compile instance and static methods with the same name - this may be a similar error

Comment: i reinstalled VS 11 beta this morning, should be ok. cant figure out where fsc is set in VS11 though..

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to *overload* the member `Release`.  It doesn't make sense to talk about *overriding* a static member with an instance member, since overriding has to do with inheritance.

Comment: indeed, I will change the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to work around this issue; you'll need to pick a different name for one the properties, unfortunately.  I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior or an unintentional limitation, but you can't define two properties with the same name, even if one is static and the other is not.  Likewise, property names must also differ from method names, even if their static-ness is different.